# Displaying all fields of a custom content

Tags: nodes

I have a `page.tpl.php` ; where I want to display inside a `<div>` in it the fields of a custom content I've created before :

1)The custom content is called "**Slider**"

2)It have a field I've added called image (Machine name :"`field_image_slider`")

I've tried this code but it didn't works :

```
    <?php
        if (!empty($node)) :
           $fieldImage = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_slider');
           print var_dump($node); //to check the fields 
           foreach ($node->field_image_slider['und'] as $item) {
              $val=$item['uri'];
              print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($val). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
           } 
        endif;
    ?>
```

I've spent 3 days figuring how to solve this problem , any help would be extremely appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong theme template. This way you need use node.tpl.php and  exactly is node--slider.tpl.php. You can see [template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656). Or you don't want use node template i think better you can use [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    $field_images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_slider');
    //dpm($field_images);
    if (!empty($field_images)) {
      $output = '';
      foreach ($field_images as $key => $images) {
        $output .= '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($images['uri']). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
      }
      $vars['slider'] = $output;
    }
  }
}
```

and in page.tpl.php

```
<?php if(isset($slider)): ?>
  <?php print $slider; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: its displaying error :
Notice: Undefined variable: slider in include() (line 79 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\Themes\fruition\templates\page.tpl.php).

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but why its displaying  this error ?
why $slider is undefined in page.tpl.php ??

Comment: what your url? do you clear cache? And with my code error will don't show because i check isset of variable slider before print it.

Comment: yea yea the error is not showing, and yes I cleared the cache, but its $slider is not being set , so that it won' t print it!

Comment: The error that i've said before is showing when I remove if(isset($slider)) ; that means that page.tpl.php is not getting this variable from template.php ; how to fix that ?

Comment: What your page url? And can you show message after uncomment in my questions(require module devel ) line //dpm($field_images);